# jquery incorrect first text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup. It has three text input fields. All of them have some values that have been set up via another form. The second and third fields have the correct value when I focus on them.

On focusing on the first field, I don't get the content as expected. I have used html() function of jquery to display the content in these text input fields.

A screenshot is here: [image]

A snippet of my ready function is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $( "body" ).delegate( ".editDiv", "click", function() {
     changed_id = this.id
     var copyData = $("#" + changed_id).html();
     var changed_class = "edit";
     var new_input = "<input id=" + changed_id + " " + "class=" + changed_class + ">";
     var editableText = $(new_input);
     editableText.val(copyData);
     $(this).replaceWith(editableText);
     editableText.focus(function() { $(this).select(); });
 });
```

The same code returns correct values for 2nd and 3rd fields. But it is not so for the first field. What could be the possible reason?

**Edit**
The HTML code for the popup is:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add advance">
<h4> 
  <b>
    {{ full_name }}
  </b> 
  <span> 
    <small>
      {{ month_name }} {{ year }}
    </small> 
  </span> 
</h4>

<table id="special" class="table" style="width: 70%; margin: auto;"> 
  <tbody> 
    {% for a in old_advances %}
      <tr> 
        <td class="text-right popup">
          <span style="float:left;"> {{ a.advance_date }} </span>
          <div class="editDiv" id="{{a.id}}">{{ a.advance_amount|floatformat:2 }} 
        </td> 
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
      <p> No advance given this month.</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: try using .text() instead of .html()

Comment: Use .val() instead of .html()

Comment: Use `.val()`  to get the value and `.text()` to get the text of dropdown-list, By using `.html()` you will get the whole HTML markup, which is not required here. Also instead of using  `.delegate`  you should use `.on'

Comment: Don't see closing tag of `div` of `.editDiv`

Comment: You should add the relevant codes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `val` to get the value of input(textbox, checkbox,  etc.).

```
var copyData = $.trim($("#" + changed_id).val());
```

To get the value of `select` dropdown:

```
var copyData = $.trim($("#" + changed_id +" option:selected").val());
```

**OR**

If you want to get the inner text(div, span, etc.) use `text`:

```
var copyData = $.trim($("#" + changed_id).text());
```

You might also want to `trim` it to remove extra spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: I missed mentioning I have tried `val` and `text`. On using `val` I get only `Kamalpreet` instead of the integer value I want to have.

Comment: Also since I am a newbie, how did you know I had to `trim` the spaces? Well that also has been an issue. Thanks for quick replies.

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal Please add complete relevant code in question. Add your html code also

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal You want value from `select` dropdown?

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal  Add your HTML or create http://jsfiddle.net/ which helps users to solve it easily

Comment: I have made the edits. @Tushar no it is not a `select` dropdown.

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal You should use `text` since you have `div`

Comment: I get the same result on using val and text i.e. `Kamalpreet`.

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal `<div class="editDiv" id="{{a.id}}">{{ a.advance_amount|floatformat:2 }}` is not closed. Add `</div>`

Comment: @KamalpreetGrewal Create jsfiddle of the same